# How can i remove the margins in Window_Base?

Tags: ruby, rpg-maker-xp

So i am remaking `Window_Status` for my game where i have the character battler displayed in the background. bellow is the portion of the script which adds the battler image taken from `def refresh` (the first part, i omitted the at-the-time experimental code for Status Icons and Stats)

```
bitmap = RPG::Cache.battler(@actor.battler_name+"_menu", @actor.battler_hue)
cw = bitmap.width
ch = bitmap.height
src_rect = Rect.new(0, 0, cw,ch)
self.contents.blt(0,0, bitmap, src_rect, 75)
draw_actor_name(@actor, 0, 0)
draw_actor_level(@actor, 80,0)
draw_actor_class(@actor, 0, 32)
```

and this is the result

[image: status]

now the battler image used is about 5x larger than the regular one (because stretching it using code made it look pixely, this way it's a bit more smoother) and also i've chopped off the left side because some of the battlers i use don't have their head perfectly centered (this way they can all can get set at 0,0)

however as you can see the bottom, which isn't cropped in the original image, is still being chopped off at the bottom. also despite the bitmap being at 0,0 it's not flesh against the sides.

i'd like to know how i can remove these margins? ideally at the `Window_Base` level since i can see myself running into the same problem with `Window_Command`

NOTE: this is in RPG Maker XP so i'm using RGSS

Comment: I'm not familiar with RPG Maker itself, but for the window, it's basically a Windows thing. And in that case, the only window i can imagine without any borders, margins or preseverd spaces, is the ToolTip window. Maybe you can use this window for your purpose?

Comment: Have you tried negative positions (hacky but might work)?
In your provided code, what does `self` refer to specifically?

Comment: @sokkyoku negative positions, or anything that would be outside the window's dimensions would produce those arrows that would indicate scrolling wouldn't they? at least that's what happens to the right and bottom of a window when i resize to to be smaller after generating a menu  (which `Window_Command` is a child of `Window_Base`) and the graphics for those arrows are a set of 4 arrows. anyway a negative position wouldn't solve the bottom of the image being cut off at the bottom.

Comment: @sokkyoku as for `self` it's the class itself....that should be obvious since this is Object Oriented Programming which anyone who used RGSS would know. i did provide my code and i did say i'm remaking `Window_Status`, unless it wasn't obvious the code comes from `def refresh` (but i'll edit that in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. the margin is being set by the hidden Window Class which makes it that much harder to alter.

However i came across [this script](http://save-point.org/thread-2714.html)

```
#==============================================================================
# ? Window - Hidden RGSS Class
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ?by Selwyn
#==============================================================================

#==============================================================================
# ? Bitmap
#==============================================================================

class Bitmap
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? erase
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def erase(*args)
    if args.size == 1
      rect = args[0]
    elsif args.size == 4
      rect = Rect.new(*args)
    end
    fill_rect(rect, Color.new(0, 0, 0, 0))
  end
end

#==============================================================================
# ? SG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ?Selwyn's Graphics module
#==============================================================================

module SG
#==============================================================================
# ? SG::Skin
#==============================================================================

class Skin
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? instances settings
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  attr_reader   :margin
  attr_accessor :bitmap
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? initialize
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def initialize
    @bitmap = nil
    @values = {}
    @values['bg'] = Rect.new(0, 0, 128, 128)
    @values['pause0'] = Rect.new(160, 64, 16, 16)
    @values['pause1'] = Rect.new(176, 64, 16, 16)
    @values['pause2'] = Rect.new(160, 80, 16, 16)
    @values['pause3'] = Rect.new(176, 80, 16, 16)
    @values['arrow_up'] = Rect.new(152, 16, 16, 8)
    @values['arrow_down'] = Rect.new(152, 40, 16, 8)
    @values['arrow_left'] = Rect.new(144, 24, 8, 16)
    @values['arrow_right'] = Rect.new(168, 24, 8, 16)
    self.margin = 16
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? width
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def margin=(width)
    @margin = width
    set_values
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? set_values
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def set_values
    w = @margin
    @values['ul_corner'] = Rect.new(128, 0, w, w)
    @values['ur_corner'] = Rect.new(192-w, 0, w, w)
    @values['dl_corner'] = Rect.new(128, 64-w, w, w)
    @values['dr_corner'] = Rect.new(192-w, 64-w, w, w)
    @values['up'] = Rect.new(128+w, 0, 64-2*w, w)
    @values['down'] = Rect.new(128+w, 64-w, 64-2*w, w)
    @values['left'] = Rect.new(128, w, w, 64-2*w)
    @values['right'] = Rect.new(192-w, w, w, 64-2*w)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? []
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def [](value)
    return @values[value]
  end
end


#==============================================================================
# ? SG::Cursor_Rect
#==============================================================================

class Cursor_Rect < ::Sprite
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? instances settings
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  attr_reader   :height, :width, :skin, :margin
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? initialize
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def initialize(viewport)
    super(viewport)
    @width = 0
    @height = 0
    @skin = nil
    @margin = 0
    @rect = {}
    @rect['cursor_up'] = Rect.new(129, 64, 30, 1)
    @rect['cursor_down'] = Rect.new(129, 95, 30, 1)
    @rect['cursor_left'] = Rect.new(128, 65, 1, 30)
    @rect['cursor_right'] = Rect.new(159, 65, 1, 30)
    @rect['upleft'] = Rect.new(128, 64, 1, 1)
    @rect['upright'] = Rect.new(159, 64, 1, 1)
    @rect['downleft'] = Rect.new(128, 95, 1, 1)
    @rect['downright'] = Rect.new(159, 95, 1, 1)
    @rect['bg'] = Rect.new(129, 65, 30, 30)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? margin=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def margin=(margin)
    @margin = margin
    set(x, y, width, height)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? skin=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def skin=(skin)
    @skin = skin
    draw_rect
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? width=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def width=(width)
    return if @width == width
    @width = width
    if @width == 0 and self.bitmap != nil
      self.bitmap.dispose
      self.bitmap = nil
    end
    draw_rect
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? height=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def height=(height)
    return if @height == height
    @height = height
    if @height == 0 and self.bitmap != nil
      self.bitmap.dispose
      self.bitmap = nil
    end
    draw_rect
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? set
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def set(x, y, width, height)
    self.x = x + @margin
    self.y = y + @margin
    if @width != width or @height != height
      @width = width
      @height = height
      if width > 0 and height > 0
        draw_rect
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? empty
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def empty
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.width = 0
    self.height = 0
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? draw_rect
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def draw_rect
    return if @skin == nil
    if @width > 0 and @height > 0
      self.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width, @height)
      rect = Rect.new(1, 1, @width - 2, @height - 2)
      self.bitmap.stretch_blt(rect, @skin, @rect['bg'])
      self.bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin, @rect['upleft'])
      self.bitmap.blt(@width-1, 0, @skin, @rect['upright'])
      self.bitmap.blt(0, @height-1, @skin, @rect['downright'])
      self.bitmap.blt(@width-1, @height-1, @skin, @rect['downleft'])
      rect = Rect.new(1, 0, @width - 2, 1)
      self.bitmap.stretch_blt(rect, @skin, @rect['cursor_up'])
      rect = Rect.new(0, 1, 1, @height - 2)
      self.bitmap.stretch_blt(rect, @skin, @rect['cursor_left'])
      rect = Rect.new(1, @height-1, @width - 2, 1)
      self.bitmap.stretch_blt(rect, @skin, @rect['cursor_down'])
      rect = Rect.new(@width - 1, 1, 1, @height - 2)
      self.bitmap.stretch_blt(rect, @skin, @rect['cursor_right'])
    end
  end
end

#==============================================================================
# ? SG::Window
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ?
#==============================================================================

class Window
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? set instances variables
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  attr_reader(:x, :y, :z, :width, :height, :ox, :oy, :opacity, :back_opacity,
              :stretch, :contents_opacity, :visible, :pause)
  attr_accessor :active
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? initialize
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def initialize()
    @skin = Skin.new
    @viewport = Viewport.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
    @cr_vport = Viewport.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
    @width = 0
    @height = 0
    @ox = 0
    @oy = 0
    @opacity = 255
    @back_opacity = 255
    @contents_opacity = 255
    @frame   = Sprite.new()
    @bg      = Sprite.new()
    @window  = Sprite.new(@viewport)
    @pause_s = Sprite.new()
    @arrows = []
    for i in 0...4
      @arrows.push(Sprite.new(@cr_vport))
      @arrows[i].bitmap = Bitmap.new(16, 16)
      @arrows[i].visible = false
    end
    @cursor_rect = Cursor_Rect.new(@cr_vport)
    @cursor_rect.margin = @skin.margin
    @cursor_fade = true
    @pause_s.visible = false
    @pause = false
    @active = true
    @stretch = true
    @visible = true
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.z = 100
    self.windowskin = RPG::Cache.windowskin($game_system.windowskin_name)
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? contents=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def contents=(bmp)
    @window.bitmap = bmp
    if bmp != nil
      if bmp.width > @viewport.rect.width
         bmp.height > @viewport.rect.height
        draw_arrows
      end
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? contents
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def contents
    return @window.bitmap
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? dispose
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def dispose
    @bg.dispose
    @frame.dispose
    @window.dispose
    @cursor_rect.dispose
    @viewport.dispose
    @pause_s.dispose
    @cr_vport.dispose
    for arrow in @arrows
      arrow.dispose
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? update
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def update
    @window.update
    @cursor_rect.update
    @viewport.update
    @cr_vport.update
    @pause_s.src_rect = @skin["pause#{(Graphics.frame_count / 8) % 4}"]
    @pause_s.update
    update_visible
    update_arrows
    if @cursor_fade
      @cursor_rect.opacity -= 10
      @cursor_fade = false if @cursor_rect.opacity <= 100
    else
      @cursor_rect.opacity += 10
      @cursor_fade = true if @cursor_rect.opacity >= 255
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? update_visible
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def update_visible
    @frame.visible = @visible
    @bg.visible = @visible
    @window.visible = @visible
    @cursor_rect.visible = @visible
    if @pause
      @pause_s.visible = @visible
    else
      @pause_s.visible = false
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? pause=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def pause=(pause)
    @pause = pause
    update_visible
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? update_arrows
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def update_arrows
    if @window.bitmap == nil or @visible == false
      for arrow in @arrows
        arrow.visible = false
      end
    else
      @arrows[0].visible = @oy > 0
      @arrows[1].visible = @ox > 0
      @arrows[2].visible = (@window.bitmap.width - @ox) > @viewport.rect.width
      @arrows[3].visible = (@window.bitmap.height - @oy) > @viewport.rect.height
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? visible=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def visible=(visible)
    @visible = visible
    update_visible
    update_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? x=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def x=(x)
    @x = x
    @bg.x = x + 2
    @frame.x = x
    @viewport.rect.x = x + @skin.margin
    @cr_vport.rect.x = x
    @pause_s.x = x + (@width / 2) - 8
    set_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? y=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def y=(y)
    @y = y
    @bg.y = y + 2
    @frame.y = y
    @viewport.rect.y = y + @skin.margin
    @cr_vport.rect.y = y
    @pause_s.y = y + @height - @skin.margin
    set_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? z=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def z=(z)
    @z = z
    @bg.z = z
    @frame.z = z + 1
    @cr_vport.z = z + 2
    @viewport.z = z + 3
    @pause_s.z = z + 4
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? ox=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def ox=(ox)
    return if @ox == ox
    @ox = ox
    @viewport.ox = ox
    update_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? oy=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def oy=(oy)
    return if @oy == oy
    @oy = oy
    @viewport.oy = oy
    update_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? width=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def width=(width)
    @width = width
    @viewport.rect.width = width - @skin.margin * 2
    @cr_vport.rect.width = width
    if @width > 0 and @height > 0
      @frame.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width, @height)
      @bg.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width - 4, @height - 4)
      draw_window
    end
    self.x = @x
    self.y = @y
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? height=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def height=(height)
    @height = height
    @viewport.rect.height = height - @skin.margin * 2
    @cr_vport.rect.height = height
    if @height > 0 and @width > 0
      @frame.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width, @height)
      @bg.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width - 4, @height - 4)
      draw_window
    end
    self.x = @x
    self.y = @y
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? opacity=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def opacity=(opacity)
    value = [[opacity, 255].min, 0].max
    @opacity = value
    @contents_opacity = value
    @back_opacity = value
    @frame.opacity = value
    @bg.opacity = value
    @window.opacity = value
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? back_opacity=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def back_opacity=(opacity)
    value = [[opacity, 255].min, 0].max
    @back_opacity = value
    @bg.opacity = value
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? contents_opacity=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def contents_opacity=(opacity)
    value = [[opacity, 255].min, 0].max
    @contents_opacity = value
    @window.opacity = value
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? cursor_rect
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def cursor_rect
    return @cursor_rect
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? cursor_rect=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def cursor_rect=(rect)
    @cursor_rect.x = rect.x
    @cursor_rect.y = rect.y
    if @cursor_rect.width != rect.width or @cursor_rect.height != rect.height
      @cursor_rect.set(@cursor_rect.x, @cursor_rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? windowskin
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def windowskin
    return @skin.bitmap
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? windowskin=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def windowskin=(windowskin)
    return if windowskin == nil
    if @skin.bitmap != windowskin
      @pause_s.bitmap = windowskin
      @pause_s.src_rect = @skin['pause0']
      @skin.bitmap = windowskin
      @cursor_rect.skin = windowskin
      draw_window
      draw_arrows
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? margin=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def margin=(margin)
    if @skin.margin != margin
      @skin.margin = margin
      self.x = @x
      self.y = @y
      temp = @height
      self.height = 0
      self.width = @width
      self.height = temp
      @cursor_rect.margin = margin
      set_arrows
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? stretch=
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def stretch=(bool)
    if @stretch != bool
      @stretch = bool
      draw_window
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? set_arrows
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def set_arrows
    @arrows[0].x = @width / 2 - 8
    @arrows[0].y = 8
    @arrows[1].x = 8
    @arrows[1].y = @height / 2 - 8
    @arrows[2].x = @width - 16
    @arrows[2].y = @height / 2 - 8
    @arrows[3].x = @width / 2 - 8
    @arrows[3].y = @height - 16
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? draw_arrows
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def draw_arrows
    return if @skin.bitmap == nil
    @arrows[0].bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['arrow_up'])
    @arrows[1].bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['arrow_left'])
    @arrows[2].bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['arrow_right'])
    @arrows[3].bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['arrow_down'])
    update_arrows
  end
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ? draw_window
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def draw_window
    return if @skin.bitmap == nil
    return if @width == 0 or @height == 0
    m = @skin.margin
    if @frame.bitmap.nil?
      @frame.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width, @height)
      @bg.bitmap = Bitmap.new(@width - 4, @height - 4)
    end
    @frame.bitmap.clear
    @bg.bitmap.clear
    if @stretch
      dest_rect = Rect.new(0, 0, @width-4, @height-4)
      @bg.bitmap.stretch_blt(dest_rect, @skin.bitmap, @skin['bg'])
    else
      bgw = Integer((@width-4) / 128) + 1
      bgh = Integer((@height-4) / 128) + 1
      for x in 0..bgw
        for y in 0..bgh
          @bg.bitmap.blt(x * 128, y * 128, @skin.bitmap, @skin['bg'])
        end
      end
    end
    bx = Integer((@width - m*2) / @skin['up'].width) + 1
    by = Integer((@height - m*2) / @skin['left'].height) + 1
    for x in 0..bx
      w = @skin['up'].width
      @frame.bitmap.blt(x * w + m, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['up'])
      @frame.bitmap.blt(x * w + m, @height - m, @skin.bitmap, @skin['down'])
    end
    for y in 0..by
      h = @skin['left'].height
      @frame.bitmap.blt(0, y * h + m, @skin.bitmap, @skin['left'])
      @frame.bitmap.blt(@width - m, y * h + m, @skin.bitmap, @skin['right'])
    end
    @frame.bitmap.erase(@width - m, 0, m, m)
    @frame.bitmap.erase(0, @height - m, m, m)
    @frame.bitmap.erase(@width - m, @height - m, m, m)
    @frame.bitmap.blt(0, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['ul_corner'])
    @frame.bitmap.blt(@width - m, 0, @skin.bitmap, @skin['ur_corner'])
    @frame.bitmap.blt(0, @height - m, @skin.bitmap, @skin['dl_corner'])
    @frame.bitmap.blt(@width - m, @height - m, @skin.bitmap, @skin['dr_corner'])
  end
end

end
```

the creator says it's the same Window Class with the added functionality to alter the margin. do to use this i had to first add the script in (i put it at the very top) then edit `Window_Base` and replace which class it inherits from `Window` to `SG::Window`. from there i was able to alter the margin

running though all the default Scene classes (like `Scene_Equip`, `Scene_Item`, etc) everything remains the same. setting the margin to 0 will cut off the Windowskin border

[image: Scene_Equip][image: Scene_Status]

as you can see on the right the background battler is now flesh against the borders by setting `self.margin=3`. you can also see that there is a slight glitch that the corners of the border are being tiled as well (only really evident with a gradient border) if the margin is altered as on the left is the default `Scene_Equip` which does not have this problem, however this is easily fixed with a bit of tinkering in the Windowskin image